# React: Get target's DOM children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say you have an HTML unordered list, and you'd like to create a React element from it:

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Another thing</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Third thing</a></li>
</ul>
```

then in JS:

```
ReactDOM.render(<MyNewList />, document.getElementById('mylist'));
```

I'd like to retrieve the original HTML LIs and use them in my MyNewList component. Something like:

```
class MyNewList extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        let listArray = this.props.whatever
    }
    ...
}
```

Is that possible? How?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve this: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/BLbjEJ

It's a rough structure, so you would have to refactor it a bit so that it fits your desired use.

**HTML:**

```
<body>

  <ul id="mylist">
    <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Another thing</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Third thing</a></li>
  </ul>

</body>
```

**JS:**

```
class MyNewList  extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      myList: null
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const myList = document.getElementById('mylist').children;
    this.setState({
      myList: myList
    });
  }

  render() {
    let renderList = 'Loading...'

    if (this.state.myList) {
      renderList = Array.prototype.map.call(this.state.myList, function(item) {
        return (
          <li>{item.textContent} found in HTML</li>
        );
      });
    }

    return (
      <ul id="myNewlist">
        {renderList}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyNewList />,
  document.getElementById('mylist')
);
```

Comment: Hi Piotr, yes! That would address my issue. Please take a look at the solution I posted (a moment after you). It is essentially the same idea, but rather passes the nodelist in as a prop to the component.

Comment: Makes sense as well. All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have those Li's be a component themselves and use them where they are currently.  That way you can reuse them anywhere else?

```
class MyNewList extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    let listArray = this.props.whatever
  }
  render() {
    return (<ul id="mylist">
      <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Another thing</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Third thing</a></li>
      </ul>)
  }    
}
```

then just pop this in wherever you want to use it.

Comment: I have fairly involved markup within each LI. The content is determined by the server. I could, perhaps, have the server template write meta tags with all the content I need to the DOM, but that's messy. In addition, if react doesn't load on this page, I'd rather there be an elegant fallback. Do you have a solution for my original question?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution (though if someone else finds a better one please post!):

JS:

```
let target = document.getElementById('mylist');
let liArray = target.getElementsByTagName('li');
ReactDOM.render(<MyNewList list={liArray} />, target);
```

then in JSX

```
class MyNewList extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        let liArray = [...this.props.list], // converts nodelist into array
            createMarkup = (el) => { return {__html: el}; }, // https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html
            convertedArray = liArray.map((slide) => {
                return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(slide.outerHTML)} />;
            });

        this.setState({
            list: convertedArray
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

There's a slightly annoying side effect of each item being wrapped in a `<div>`, but I'm tweaking the above so that the result is valid HTML5 syntax for my application.